# I want to send a HTTP POST Request to a .Net Web Service with some headers using PHP

Tags: php, web-services

I newbie in PHP developing and I am trying to post a Request to .Net Web Service with some headers, this how it looks:

```
POST /Service1.asmx/importaContactos HTTP/1.1
Host: 38.127.113.211
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

nombre=string&fijo=string&campania=string&agente=string&extra1=string&extra2=string&extra3=string&extra4=string&extra5=string
```

I have to send the data from PHP form

Answer (score 0):

You need use curl for this task. You can read more here https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

curl is built in php library.